# ng-repeat is not producing result in correct format

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs and working on creating a sample application. I was making use of `ng-repeat` directive. My controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('CustomerController',function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{ Name: 'Emp One' }, { Age: 10 }, { Salary: 100000000 },
    { Name: 'Emp Two' }, { Age: 20 }, { Salary: 2000000 },
    { Name: 'Emp Three' }, { Age: 30 }, { Salary: 300000000 }];

    $scope.AddCustomer = function() {
        $scope.customers.push($scope.NewCutomer.Name, $scope.NewCutomer.Age, $scope.NewCutomer.Salary);
    };
})
```

Now on the view I am just printing the output.

```
<div ng-repeat="cust in customers">
    <p>Name:   {{cust.Name}}  Age:  {{cust.Age}}   Salary: {{cust.Salary}}</p>   
</div>
```

Look at the below image, instead of producing 3 lines, system is generating 9 lines.

[image]

**I want output like**

```
Name: EmpOne Age: 10 Salary: 10000000
Name: EmpTwo Age: 30 Salary: 2000000
Name: EmpThree Age: 30 Salary: 300000000
```

Comment: You are creating separate name, emp and salary objects instead of customer objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object is formatted incorrectly, it should be:

```
$scope.customers = [{ Name: "Emp One", Age: 10, Salary: 100000000 },
```

And so on. Else, each object gets a new line, like your current result.